# How to prove that $q_1=xq_1+yq_1+\lambda$ is equal to $q_1=(x+y)^*$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata, regular-expressions

> Suppose we have the following automaton:
>
> [image: Automaton]
>
> Find the regular expression.

By inspection we could say that the regular expression is $x(x+y)^*$, but I want to prove it by solving the system of equations: $$\begin{cases}q_0=xq_1\\q_1=xq_1+yq_1+\lambda\end{cases}$$ I am not able to reduce $q_1$.

I know the rule says if $p=ap+bq$ then $p=a^*(bq)=a^*bq$, but here I cannot apply this rule because I have a term (the null word $\lambda$) that is not of the form $bq$ i.e. I cannot do the following: $$q_1=xq_1+yq_1+\lambda\neq x^*(yq_1+\lambda)=x^*yq_1+x^*\lambda=x^*yq_1+x^*.$$ So my question is:

> How can we arrive at the following equality?: $$q_1=xq_1+yq_1+\lambda=(x+y)^*$$

Comment: Oh I thought the following: $q_1=xq_1+yq_1+\lambda$ means $q_1=xq_1$ or $q_1=yq_1$ or $q_1=\lambda$. Now we can apply a rule to the first two expressions to obtain $q_1=x^*$ or $q_1=y^*$ or $q_1=\lambda$. Then by addition, $q_1=x^*+y^*$ or $q_1=\lambda$, i.e., $q_1=(x+y)^*$ or $q_1=\lambda$. Again by addition we finish by saying $q_1=(x+y)^*+\lambda$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rewrite $q_1 = xq_1 + yq_1 + \lambda$ as $q_1 = (x+y)q_1 + \lambda$. By [Arden's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arden%27s_rule), you get 
$$q_1 = (x+y)^*\lambda = (x+y)^*.$$

Comment: Oh, distributive was the key. Thank you you've helped me a lot!!